# asp.net core Angular Template how to add site.css

Tags: css, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Just starting out with the new angular templates in VS Code. Im trying to accomplish what feels like should be the simplest of tasks which is just wanting to add a site level css file to the web project to apply some styles.

From all the google examples i've seen is referring to updating the Angular-cli.json file to attach the to the output but this file isn't available in the core angular template. Where abouts should the css file go and how to link it so it applies site wide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a .Net Core web project with Angular template, you should see `ClientApp` folder in the project. My machine has just installed the latest **.Net Core 2.1 SDK** and **nodejs (v 8.11.3 LTS)**, and has the Visual Studio Community 15.7.3.

[image]

You can apply the site-wide styles to `styles.css` file, under `ClientApp -> src`.

If you have more site-wide style files, you can configure them in `.angular-cli.json` file.

[image]

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the reply. I can see the ClientApp folder, but there is no src folder under it. Am i meant to create that to hold the styles.css? Also, referring to your last line, angular-cli.json doesn't exist in the .net core web project with Angular Template?

Comment: Weird. Make sure your development machine has installed the latest .Net Core SDK and nodejs (and maybe angular cli)?? See my updated OP with screenshots.

Comment: Awesome. I was on .net core 2.0, so i've upgraded to the latest sdk and now the solution looks similar to the one that you have posted. Thanks for your help

Comment: Upgrading from 2.0 to 2.1. They've changed a hell of a lot for their angular template. Any ideas why they removed all the default hot loading stuff with webpack out?